# Разное время выполнения DELETE запросов

Tags: mysql, sql

Приветствую други и коллеги. Бывает такое, что чищу большую базу (по количеству записей) и данный процесс затягивается на долгое время. Молчу про время удаления записей с более сложным запросом..

**Поэтому возникает вопросик**, почему первый запросик удаляет очень быстро 600к записей, а на другой таблице для удаления 600к записей понадобится 3-4 минуты?

```
sql> DELETE FROM log WHERE date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ORDER BY date DESC
[2017-11-09 10:00:41] 603420 rows affected in 7s 995ms

sql> DELETE FROM node WHERE node_id<2700000
[2017-11-09 10:09:07] 235408 rows affected in 1m 22s 381ms
```

DDL таблиц:

```
create table log
(
    id int not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    node_id int not null,
    serv_id int not null,
    ip varchar(20) null,
    date datetime not null
)
;
create table node
(
    node_id int not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    node_code varchar(20) not null,
    serv_id int not null,
    full_status text null,
    constraint node_code_serv_id
    unique (node_code, serv_id)
)
;
```

Я конечно догадываюсь, что возможно это из-за ограничений, также таблица node связана ограничением с 3-ей таблицей (в 3-й таблице могут быть значения только с node_id из таблицы node). Но хотел бы услышать пояснение и советы, так как они могут понадобиться при следующем проектировании таблиц.

Comment: "также таблица node связана ограничением с 3-ей таблицей" а можно всё-таки в запросе указать всех действующих лиц? `delete` при наличии FK должен проверить выполнение ограничения FK для каждой строки.

Comment: @Мелкий ну я для начала удаляю из table3, а потом из node, чтобы не было ошибки ограничения))

Comment: а FK проверять всё равно надо.

Comment: @Мелкий я пока не дошел до этого раздела, шагов еще 150 надо. Тыкни плиз в доку. А вообще подумываю удалить это ограничение, посмотрел по некоторым CMS, там вообще ограничений нет, друпал например.

Comment: "не читайте советских газет во время еды" (с). Т.е. не смотрите всякий говнокод в качестве ориентира. Если в схеме данных есть связь - здесь должен быть FK. Во всяком случае пока не доказано, что именно в вашем конкретном случае FK обходится слишком дорого и написан план как следить и исправлять ошибки данных. Пишущие операции будут проверять все ограничения таблицы и ограничения ссылающиеся на эту таблицу чтобы оставить данные в согласованном виде (цитату в мануале искать не хочу, это и так очевидно должно быть). Совершенно логично, что проверка ограничений займёт некоторое время.

Comment: связи в CMS это плохой пример. Ибо обычно они реализуют ORM модели, и проверяют ограничения и делают каскадные действия вручную. То есть эта задача переносится с БД на фреймворк, туда где модели данных описываются, а не где хранятся. Так что в таких БД могут быть первичные ключи и индексы. каких то внешних ключей и каскадных удалений там не будет.

Comment: `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` вроде такая штука есть, может отключить и проверить время